# GitLab rendering the wrong README in Project & Public views

Tags: r, gitlab

I'm using R markdown (`README.Rmd`) to knit/render to `README.md` at the top level of a project directory. GitLab (both in Project and Public views) chooses the `.Rmd` file to render vs the `.md` file  and produces a visual mess instead of a nicely-formatted project description.

Is there any way to tell GitLab to ignore `.Rmd` files when picking the "right" one to use for the project/public view or am I left with a workflow that will mean keeping the `README.Rmd` in a separate directory then having the R project build process render and copy a knitted `README.md` to the top-level project directory?

This is a fresh install (this week) of a self-hosted instance of GitLab, but you can see it rendering the wrong `README` [here](https://gitlab.dds.ec/public/projects/bob.rudis/iptools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced this issue. I'll look into this tomorrow and make a PR for fixing this.

Comment: I actually want it to render the `.md` file (which is there) and not the `.Rmd`. My build process knits the final markdown doc. I'd rather not have the `.Rmd` file in another directory, too, but I might just go that route.

Comment: Thx. Was on mobile app version with limited time to respond. So far the rest of the GitLab experience has been great.

Comment: Started in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/7466. If there is no proper renderer, the file is rendered without markup but preserve line endings. Looks the following: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qrh0sv6or8uwxzk/Screenshot%202014-08-10%2014.37.19.png

Comment: PR merged :) Will be available in GitLab 7.2